# Plotting octahedron inside the sphere and sphere inside the cube

Tags: plotting

How to plot an octahedron inside a sphere and the same sphere inside a cube in 3d?

Comment: Take a look at `PolyhedronData` and `GeometricTransform`. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried in graphics 3D for the circumsphere of octahedron. But the output is saying octahedron is not a graphic 3d primitive.I did not understand this.

Comment: Hard do say anything without a code sample. Also, make sure you went through examples in documentation I mentioned.

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.25], PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "Faces"],Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1/Sqrt[2]],Cuboid[1/Sqrt[2] {-1, -1, -1}, 1/Sqrt[2] {1, 1, 1}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: One can use [`Octahedron`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Octahedron.html) as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
cs = Circumsphere @ Octahedron[];

cuboid = Cuboid @@ Transpose[RegionBounds[cs]];

Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.6, Red], Octahedron[],
  Opacity[.4, Blue], cs, 
  Opacity[.4, Yellow], cuboid}]
```

[image]